# Pass by address (pointer)

Tags: c, pointers

```
void fun(char* name);

int main(){
    char* name = NULL;
    fun(name);
    printf("%s",name);
}

void fun(char* name){
    char input[SIZE];
    int length;

    printf("Please enter a name:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    length = strlen(input);
    name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1);
    if(name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(name, input);
}
```

What am I missing, I am trying to assign the string to the pointer, the scope of the malloc in not just in the function, so where is the mistake?

Comment: You are trying to copy contents of a variable to an unallocated poniter. If it was just referencing, then it might have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make *name* an output parameter if you continue to give it as a parameter, currently it is only local and no change are visible outside *fun*

```
void fun(char** name);

int main(){
    char* name = NULL;
    fun(&name);
    printf("%s",name);
}

void fun(char** name){
    char input[SIZE];
    int length;

    printf("Please enter a name:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    length = strlen(input);
    *name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1);
    if(*name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(*name, input);
}
```

As you see I give the address of the variable *name* allowing to modify its value in *fun*, so the type is the pointer of a `char*` being a `char**`

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter a name:
aze
aze
```

You miss to free *name*

**Warning** : If the input is greater than *SIZE* you will have an undefined behavior writing out of *input*, supposing SIZE is not a constant or can change later is is better to do something like that :

```
void fun(char** name){
    char input[SIZE];
    int length;
    char fmt[16];

    printf("Please enter a name:\n");

    sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", SIZE);
    scanf(fmt, input);
    length = strlen(input);
    *name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1);
    if(*name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(*name, input);
}
```

As you see I make the format of the *scanf*, for instance if *SIZE* values 10 the used format will be "%10s"

Comment: Thanks ok, I know that it will not be more then size

Comment: @gbox if needed in an other case in the future you will know how to do ^^

Answer (score 6):

You're passing in a copy of a pointer, changing that pointer, and not sending the pointer back. Any modifications to `name` only exist within that function unless you either pass in a double-pointer or instead take the simple approach of returning a value.

Rework the function to return a pointer that you can use:

```
char* fun() {
    char input[SIZE];
    int length;

    printf("Please enter a name:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    length = strlen(input);

    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1);

    if(name == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(name, input);

    return name;
}
```

Then when you call it you can do a direct assignment:

```
int main(){
    char* name = fun();

    printf("%s",name);

    free(name);

    return 0;
}
```

There's no benefit to passing in a pointer. Whatever pointer you pass in gets changed, the original value is not used, which means that's not useful.

Remember you don't need to pre-declare your functions if you declare `main()` last, as is tradition. Don't forget to `return` an `int` in that function as well. When compiling use `-Wall` to alert for common mistakes.

Comment: So what happen when I send just name, it is a pointer so it is passed as value

Comment: It's passed in by value, yes, as is everything is in C. It's only in C++ you have the ability to pass in by reference. C can pass in by value, but the value is a pointer to a pointer, which is like a reference except you need to explicitly de-reference it for the effect to happen.